# How to disable all scheduled jobs in 1C Server?

Tags: 1c

How can I disable all scheduled jobs?
When developing projects, we faced the problem of shortage and blocking of resources and processes.
We have many scheduled jobs for the server, but for development machines, they are causing issues because they do not allow updating database configuration as it keeps saying:
«InfoBase exceptional lock error.»

I have not found standard and common procedures to resolve this issue. Maybe someone has faced something like this and knows how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the server version 1C, the easiest way to block all scheduled jobs is to use the 1C server administration utility.

See screenshots below...

[first, open the properties of the database for which you want to disable scheduled jobs:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fscYe.png)

[and now put the flag "Execution of scheduled jobs is disabled"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsdFQ.png)